# Setting up production MongoDB cluster with enterprise ssd drives vs. commodity ssd drives

Tags: mongodb, solid-state-drive

I am planning out a MongoDB cluster for production across 4 servers and trying to figure out what the tradeoffs are saving money and buying commodity/user grade SSD drives like crucial vs. paying more money for enterprise ssd drives that are much more expensive like the intel enterprise S3700, S3710 or S4510 drives. We are using dell power edge servers and want to save money just don't know what the trade off is, regarding drive failure things can be monitored and replaced on the fly so that is not my concern, my concern is putting in commodity drives not knowing it will bite us in the future. Need some answers from the community.

Answer (score 1):

It is always better to run your database on expensive high performance and reliable hardware , but the biggest advantage of using mongoDB is that you can run  on cheap hardware and configure replication so even you loose often some SSD you can easily replace it and init sync until your other replicaSet members continue serving your application calls. So for mongoDB I would advice to check the SSD characteristincs like IOPS and throughput , you need hardware supporting huge amount of random small reads 4-32kB  and you need alot of RAM to avoid your SSD to die faster. Also it is important to estimate the size of your database , mongoDB recommends your single shard to not exceed 2TB  so even below that limit you will need to shard , meaning that you will need to double the amount of servers which can become expensive exercise over time if you continue with the expensive hardware...

Comment: Right, question is running on cheap SSD drives vs. enterprise, I decided to go with cheap commodity ones with the idea that if one drive fails there will be a replica. Good to know about shard size.